# Vertical alignment of boxed environment created with mdframed

Tags: floats, vertical-alignment, mdframed

I'm writing a math exercise book for my students. I want each exercice to be in a framed box so I created a new environment called "Exercice" using mdframed. I'm having trouble with the vertical alignment of all the boxes. I would like them to all stack at the top of the page but (see following example) the top box doesn't always start at the same height on the different pages. It looks like a float problem but I couldn't figure it out. Here is the code:

```latex
    \documentclass[12pt, a4paper,openany]{book}
    \usepackage[french]{babel}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%% Margins, Header & Footer
    \usepackage[top=0.0cm, bottom=0.5cm, left=0.5cm, right=0.5cm,includehead, includefoot,headheight=1cm,heightrounded,footnotesep=0cm]{geometry}
    
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancypagestyle{plain}{}
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
    \markboth{#1}{}}
    \lhead{}
    \rhead{\Large\leftmark}
    \cfoot{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
    
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%% Titles format 
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
    \usepackage{titlesec}
    \makeatletter
    \titleformat{\chapter}[display]   
    {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{}{20pt}{\@gobble} 
    \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-100pt}{0pt}
    \titlespacing{\section}{0.0pt}{0.4cm}{0.0pt}
    \titleformat{\section}[runin]{}{}{0pt}{\@gobble}
    \makeatother
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%% mdframed
    \usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
    %\mdfsetup{skipabove=0pt,skipbelow=10pt, innertopmargin = -5pt}
    
    \newcounter{exercice}
    \renewcommand{\theexercice}{\arabic{exercice}}
    \counterwithin*{exercice}{chapter}
    \newmdenv[skipabove=0pt,skipbelow=10pt, innertopmargin = 0.3cm, outerlinewidth=0pt, innerlinewidth=0.4pt, roundcorner=5pt, settings={\global\stepcounter{exercice}}
    , extra={\node[left, yshift=0.1cm, xshift=-17cm,inner sep=2pt,rectangle,fill=white] at (P){\normalsize\bfseries Exercice \theexercice};}
    ]{Exercice}
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%% Miscellaneous
    \setlength{\parindent}{0.0cm} % 
    \topskip=0pt % 
    \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}%
    \setlist[itemize]{nosep, noitemsep, label=*}
    \setlist[enumerate]{nosep, noitemsep, label=\textbf{\alph*.},leftmargin=0.9cm}
    
    
    \begin{document}
    \setlength{\baselineskip}{0.8cm}
    
    
    
    \chapter{A chapter name}
    \begin{Exercice}
    bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla 
    \end{Exercice}
    \begin{Exercice}
    bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla  
    \end{Exercice}
    \begin{Exercice}
    bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla
    \end{Exercice}
    \begin{Exercice}
    bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla
    \end{Exercice}
    \begin{Exercice}
    bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla
    \end{Exercice}
    \begin{Exercice}
    bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla 
    \end{Exercice}
    \begin{Exercice}
    bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla 
    \end{Exercice}
    \begin{Exercice}
    bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla
    \end{Exercice}
    
    %%%%%%%% Pourcentages
    \chapter{Another chapter name}
    \begin{Exercice}
    bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla  
    \end{Exercice}
    \begin{Exercice}
    bla \\ bla  
    \end{Exercice}
    \begin{Exercice}
    bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla
    \end{Exercice}
    \begin{Exercice}
    bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla 
    \end{Exercice}
    \begin{Exercice}
    bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla \\ bla
    \end{Exercice}
    \begin{Exercice}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \def\labelenumi{\textbf{\Alph{enumi}.}}
    \item Dans un magasin, l'ensemble des articles est soldé à 20\%.
        \begin{enumerate}
        \def\labelenumi{\alph{enumi}.}
        \item Combien coûtera un T-shirt valant 43 euros ?
        \item  Combien coûtera un pull valant 75 euros ?
        \end{enumerate}
    \item Un couple achète une maison à 250 000 euros. Après de nombreux travaux, la maison est finalement estimée 15\% plus cher. Combien vaudra-t-elle ?
    \item Une entreprise faisant 200 000 euros de bénéfices par an en 2021 les a vus diminuer de 18\% en 2022. Calculer les bénéfices de l'entreprise
    en 2022.
    \item Dans une entreprise, le PDG décide d'augmenter tous ses salariés de 10\%. Combien un salarié gagnant initialement 2200 euros sera finalement payé après augmentation ?
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{Exercice}
    
    \begin{Exercice}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \def\labelenumi{\textbf{\alph{enumi}.}}
    \item En France, le nombre moyen d\textquotesingle enfants par femmes était de 2, 85 en 1960. Entre 1960 et 2020, il a diminué d'environ 35, 79 \%. Calculer le nombre moyen d'enfants par femme en france en 2020. (Arrondir le résultat au centième)
    \item En moyenne, le sac Birkin de la maison Hermès coûte 8000 euros. Il est néanmoins très difficile de s'en procurer un. D'autres sites le proposent donc mais augmentent le prix de plus de 1150 \%. Calculer la valeur que peut atteindre un sac Birkin.
    \item En 2000, la population mondiale était de 6, 1 milliards. Elle a augmenté de 31\% jusqu'en 2022. Calculer la population mondiale en 2022..
    \item En 1999, le SMIC (Salaire Minimum Interprofessionnel de Croissance) en France était de 1036 euros par mois. Entre 1999 et 2023, il a augmenté d'environ 65,12 \%. Calculer le SMIC en 2023.
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{Exercice}
    \end{document}
```

Also, for some reason, the box called "Exercice 6" on page 4 is split and I don't understand why.

Any help is welcome

Thanks

Philippe

Comment: Well your chapter definition is definitively odd. Why are you using \chapter if you don't want it to print something? Use e.g. `\clearpage\chaptermark{Another chapter name}` to setup only the header. And better use tcolorbox instead of mdframed. It has much more features and gives you more control over the boxes.

Comment: Hi Ulrike, thanks for your answer. I'm trying to use tcolorbox now but I haven't been able to find how to have all my boxes stack to the top (with equal gle between boxes).